# How to create a List of Func<T1, T2, out T3>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I suspect this is more simple than I think!

I can create a list of Func and then add to it

```
var x = new List<Func<IBQCustomer, string>>();
x.Add(c => c.FullName);
```

Bu how to I add an extra parameter into the Func? When I try I get an error

```
var y = new List<Func<IBQCustomer, OrderByDirection, string>>();
y.Add(...);
```

Is this possible?

I am aiming to build up a list of properties and what to do with them

---

Error:

```
y.Add(c => c.FullName, OrderByDirection.Asc);
No overload for Add that takes 2 arguments
```

Comment: "..." = "I have no idea what to put here to add an item to my list"
One error added above

Comment: Do you want an extra parameter or an extra return value?

Comment: extra parameter - would like 3 parameters eventually...but not greedy ;) e.g. Build up a list of Func<1,2,3> so I can use it later

Comment: BTW: Can do it with a class that contains all the parameters, but this seems like it shouldn't be necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'OrderByDirection' enumeration is not a function argument? In this case you could use something like:

```
var y = new List<Tuple<Func<IBQCustomer, string>, OrderByDirection>>();
y.Add(new Tuple<Func<IBQCustomer, string>, OrderByDirection>(c => c.FullName, OrderByDirection.Asc));
```

Of course you could also use a custom class instead of 'Tuple<>':

```
class MyClass
{
    public Func<IBQCustomer, string> Function;
    public OrderByDirection Direction;
}
```

Or are you maybe writing the lambda expression wrong? This should work:

```
var y = new List<Func<IBQCustomer, OrderByDirection, string>>();
y.Add((c, d) => c.FullName);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare an anonymous delegate with multiple parameters like this:

```
y.Add((customer, direction) => customer.FullName);
```

Then it would work. Whatever is invoking each delegate in the list must then provide two arguments, `IBQCustomer` and `OrderByDirection`.